# Is there any way to access the expression from within a ruby case statement?

Tags: ruby, case

I would like to access the case statements expression from within a then clause i.e.

```
food = "cheese"
case food
when "dip" then "carrot sticks"
when "cheese" then "#{expr} crackers"
else
  "mayo"
end
```

where in this case expr would be the current value of food. In this case I know, I could simply access the variable food, however there may be cases where the value is no longer accessible (array.shift etc..). Other than moving the expr out into a local variable and then accessing it, is there a way of directly accessing the value of the cases expr?

Roja

p.s. I know that this specific example is trivial its mealy an example scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
food = "cheese"

x = case food
  when "dip" then "carrot sticks"
  when /(cheese|cream)/ then "#{ $1 } crackers"
else
  "mayo"
end

puts x  # => cheese crackers
```

Comment: Hmm i am thinking that this is indeed the "way" shame it ends up being assigned to a global :S Much appreciate the incite!

Comment: `x` here can be a variable of any scope.  It only assigns to a global if you assign it to a global.  This everything in ruby, the case state state returns a value.  You simply and optionally capture that value in a variable of your choosing.

Comment: This only seems to work if you're using matching then $1 is the result of the match.  If you aren't using matching then Wayne Conrad's answer is better and more clear.

Comment: @Josh:  Unfortunately in Wayne's solution `value` is not localised (within `case/end`) and so potential variable pollution problems arise.  I personally prefer my approach and seem to recall it also been used in the `Programming Ruby` book.

Comment: Both this solution and mine introduce a variable.  I see no difference between these solutions in that regard.

Comment: @WayneConrad - My `case` expression doesn't create any new variables.  NB.  `$1` is always available in Ruby and contains the last match performed.

Comment: I was referring to `x`.

Comment: @WayneConrad - `x` isn't created or used by the `case` expression (block).    It's only there to clarify @Roja's question & example code only.  The `case` still works if `x` is removed :)

Answer (score 10):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

a = [1, 2, 3]
case value = a.shift
when 1
  puts "one (#{value})"
when 2
  puts "two (#{value})"
end

# => one (1)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is messy but seems like it works...

```
food = "cheese"
case food
when ( choice = "dip" ): "carrot sticks"
when (choice = "cheese" ): "#{ choice } crackers"
else
  "mayo"
end
```